# How to handle semantic failures in TatSu when parsing is correct?

Tags: peg, tatsu

I am trying to create a TatSu parser for a language containing C-like expressions. I have the following grammar rules for the expressions:

```
identifier =
    /[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]*/
    ;

expression =
    or_expr
    ;

or_expr =
    '||'<{and_expr}+
    ;

and_expr =
    '&&'<{bitwise_or_expr}+
    ;

bitwise_or_expr =
    '|'<{bitwise_xor_expr}+
    ;

bitwise_xor_expr =
    '^'<{bitwise_and_expr}+
    ;

bitwise_and_expr =
    '&'<{equality_expr}+
    ;

equality_expr =
    ('==' | '!=')<{comparison_expr}+
    ;

comparison_expr =
    ('<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=')<{bitshift_expr}+
    ;

bitshift_expr =
    ('<<' | '>>')<{additive_expr}+
    ;

additive_expr =
    ('+' | '-')<{multiplicative_expr}+
    ;

multiplicative_expr =
    ('*' | '/' | '%')<{unary_expr}+
    ;

unary_expr =
    '+' ~ atom
    | '-' ~ atom
    | '~' ~ atom
    | '!' ~ atom
    | atom
    ;

atom =
    literal
    | helper_call
    | parenthesized
    | var_or_param
    ;

literal =
    value:float type:`float`
    | value:integer type:`int`
    | value:char type:`char`
    | value:string type:`string`
    | value:bool type:`int`
    | value:null type:`null`
    ;

helper_call =
    function:identifier '(' ~ params:expression_list ')'
    ;

var_or_param =
    identifier
    ;

parenthesized =
    '(' ~ @:expression ')'
    ;
```

I was running into trouble with the `atom` rule. When parsing the following (the `expression` being the part between the `=` and `;`):

```
lastTime = ts + interval;
```

I got this exception:

```
tatsu.exceptions.FailedToken: (27:41) expecting '(' :
                lastTime = ts + interval;
                                        ^
helper_call
atom
unary_expr
multiplicative_expr
...
```

It was failing trying to make it fit the `helper_call` rule, when the `var_or_param` rule should have matched just fine. It turns out, the cause was an erroneous `FailedSemantics` raised by the semantic actions for `var_or_param`. Once I fixed that, the parsing worked as expected.

This raises a question: If `FailedSemantics` affects the parsing logic, what is the proper way to alert the user when there is a semantic error, but the parse logic is otherwise correct and should not attempt different choices or rules? For example, type mismatches or variable usage before declaration? (Ideally in a way that would still show the line number where the error occurred.)

Comment: Have you tried enabling tracing, to see the progress of the parsing?

Comment: `FailedSemantics` does affect the parsing. It gets translated to a `FailedParse` in the parse logic.

Comment: @Apalala No, I will try that. For the second comment, that explains why I was having trouble, then. But that raises the real question: What is the proper way to alert the user when there is a semantic error, but the parse logic is otherwise correct and should not attempt different choices or rules? For example, if an undeclared variable is used, there is a type mismatch, etc.? Ideally in a way that would still show the line number the error occurred on? (Perhaps this should be a new question.)

Comment: Please expand your question to cover semantic errors, and I'll write a proper reply.

Comment: @Apalala Thanks. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FailedSemantic`s does affect the parsing. It gets translated to a `FailedParse` in the parse logic.

If the parsing should stop, then keep using `FailedSemantics`.

In other scenarios it's up to you.

TatSu is designed so most of semantic checks are done after the parse succeeded, through a walker or other means.

Comment: That explains why I was originally having trouble, but the core question remains: What is the proper way to signal that there is a semantic issue, but the parsing is otherwise correct? For example, type mismatches, undeclared variables, etc. If we just raise some other exception, Tatsu doesn't report any useful information like the line number.

Comment: If the parsing should stop, then keep using `FailedSemantics`. In other scenarios it's up to you. TatSu is designed so most of semantic checks are done _after_ the parse succeed, through a walker or other means.

Comment: Ok. It sounds like I was abusing the semantics class for more than was intended, then. I'll have to refactor that part of the code. (If you add that note to the answer, I can mark it as accepted.)